# Creating fontset to use it later as Character Marker Symbol in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, style, software-recommendations, font

Using Inkscape to create fonts as indicated in [Creating new custom vector marker symbol for ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32271) does not works well for me, as the drawn symbol is not aligned correctly in the Symbol Property Editor, and I don't want to set offset for each of my symbols.

[image]

What is the best software (free, if possible) to use for creating these fontsets in a correct way?

I have followed the aformentioned tutorial. The problem is, that in Inkscape the image seems centered, but the SVG font editor automatically adds some additional spaces around it (called bearings) and that makes the image to misalign to the center. Have you successfully created a centered glyph somehow?

Comment: If you don't want to set offset for each of my symbols, I would have thought that you just needed to take more care with the centering of your original drawing.  What were the precise steps that you performed to produce it?

Comment: I have followed the aformentioned tutorial. The problem is, that in Inkscape the image seems centered, but the SVG font editor automatically adds some additional spaces around it (called bearings) and that makes the image to misalign to the center. Have you successfully created a centered glyph somehow?

Comment: I think it would be useful to [edit] those additional details into your question so that it is not viewed simply as a request for a software recommendation.  There is a [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange for that.